# Isomorphism on $k[t]$, where $k$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $k$ be a field .Show that the $k-$isomorphism $k[t] \to k[t]$ is given by $t \mapsto t-a$, $i.e.$ for any other isomorphism $\phi$ , we should have $\phi (t)= f(t)$ , where $f(t) \in k[t]$, a linear polynomial.

It is obvious that the map which sends $t \mapsto t-a$ is an isomorphism on $k[t]$. but how to show the second part. I think we should prove uniqueness of such mapping..

Please someone give some hints.

Comment: I find this pretty unclear. What do do mean by "the" $k$-isomorphism? Also, do you mean as a $k$-algebra?

Comment: what is the definition of isomorphism that you are using?

Comment: Actually this is an assignment problem so I also don't know what sir has said with k-isomorphism?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't know about $k$-algebra also..so please can you give me some link so that I can find the definition of $k$ -algebra

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebra: $\phi(a)=a, a\in k$.

If $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $deg(\phi(t))>0$, we have$\phi(a_0+a_1t+..+a_nt^n)=a_0+...+a_n\phi(t^n)$. This implies that $deg(\phi(p))=ndeg(p)$ and $deg(\phi(p)>0$ if $deg(p)>0$.  Contradiction since $t$ is in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: I think we should take $deg( \phi (t)) >1$ to make contradiction as we have to prove that $\phi (t)$ is linear

Comment: it is what I did

Comment: In the contradiction : $deg(t)=1 >0$ so it satisfy what you have proved at last